# jquery Ajax doesn't show any message(neither success nor failure)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to submit a form with jquery Ajax. But it does not show any kind of message. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637019/how-to-get-the-jquery-ajax-error-response-text) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484574/jquery-ajax-doesnt-show-anything) question. But I didn't get my solution. My jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#btnSave").submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var myTableArray = [];

    $("table#vouchTable tr").not(':first').each(function () {
        var arrayOfThisRow = [];
        var tableData = $(this).find('td');
        if (tableData.length > 0) {
            tableData.each(function () { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
        }

   }); ///This Part works fine 

    ///But this part does not work 

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Accounts/VoucherEntry',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(myTableArray),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }

    });


    return false;

    ////////////////////

  });
});
```

Comment: can you include the `html` and the `VoucherEntry`

Comment: is there any error message on console? press F12 and see error

Comment: can you provide the php for the ajax?

Comment: check if the request is being sent. check it through chrome network tab

Comment: @KallolDas, check in Firebug

Comment: I tried. But I could not. The site says, "It looks that your post is most likely code........ "  @guradio

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Missing end brackets for : `$(document).ready(function () {`

Missing end brackets for : `$("#btnSave").submit(function (e) {`

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#btnSave").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var myTableArray = [];

        $("table#vouchTable tr").not(':first').each(function () {
            var arrayOfThisRow = [];
            var tableData = $(this).find('td');
            if (tableData.length > 0) {
                tableData.each(function () { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
                myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
            }

       }); 

       var data = JSON.stringify(myTableArray);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Accounts/VoucherEntry',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }

        });
     });  // <-----  Missing brackets!!!
  });    //  <-----  Missing brackets!!!
```

Comment: answering with try this without any explanation does not help the OP

Answer (score 0):

Format you data like:

```
data: {data:myTableArray},
```

in c# get the data by the key `data`